# error while initial snapshot in kafka on local (trying to CDC a production level data to local db)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

[this a warning/error in logs i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk1R2.png)

WARN [Producer clientId=connector-producer-mysql-connector-0] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 18591

i increased the java heap space and also the kafka server storage.
[the error the kafka connect gets terminated but the kafka server and zookeepers is up and running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeC3G.png)

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "kafka-producer-network-thread | connector-producer-mysql-connector-0"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Abandoned connection cleanup thread"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "debezium-mysqlconnector-dbserverkk1-snapshot"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "kafka-producer-network-thread | mysql-connector-dbhistory"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "SourceTaskOffsetCommitter-1"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "qtp1705277839-38"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "qtp1705277839-39"

Comment: That metadata fetching warning is most of the time more than just a warning. Do you have a SASL enabled broker? And what type of connector are you using, like debezium or something?

Comment: i am using debezium i found it to be a memory issue. allotted more memory on to the VM it fixed this error and also reduced the db size of the source db and it fixed them still figuring our what needed to be done for huge amount data to be snapshot

Comment: ok, glad you solved it :)